# VBA Run time error '91' - cannot figure out why error is occurring

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I want to preface this with the fact that I have no real VBA experience. I just research the Microsoft VBA reference documents and build my code piece by piece from there.
I have created a user form to collect data that is entered into a table. I wanted to be able to go through each record and retrieve/update records as needed since information is typically gathered at multiple stages.
I am getting an error on the below code (bold line erroring out):

```
Private Sub AddRecord_Click()

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Status").ListRows.Add
    **ModifyTableRow StatusTable.ListRows(StatusTable.ListRows.Count).Range**
    
    UpdatePositionCaption
    
End Sub
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and have not been able to troubleshoot on my own. I must be misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1):

`ListRows.Add` returns the just-added row, so you can use that directly in a `With` block

```
Private Sub AddRecord_Click()

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Status").ListRows.Add
         ModifyTableRow .Range
    End with
    
    UpdatePositionCaption
    
End Sub
```